# .net core web app JQuery AJAX Front end not getting data from Backend .net core api

Tags: c#, .net, ajax, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-webapi

Im doing an assesment at the moment that requires JQuery as a technology (which ive never used). Im struggling with trying to connect the frontend with the back end.

Ive written a .NET Core WebApi that has controllers for Students and Teacher(Used POSTMAN to test GET,POST,PUT,DELETE), and I will add more, but I first want to test the connection.
Then I Created a .Net Core WebApp in the same solution. When I run them though I can access all the info from postman, but the WebApp Tables values for Enrollment dates say undefined.
Table:
[image]

My JSON Response that is past to the table in 'Index':
[image]

Im sorry if this is a stupid question *Facepalm*.

Index Class in WebApp that pulls from the api URL:

```
       @{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Student";
}
<script src="~/js/jquery-3.6.0.js"></script>

<div class="panel panel-primary">
    <div class="panel-heading">
        Get API Data
        </div>
    <div class="panel-body">
        <table class="table table-bordered" id="Table">
            <tr>
                <th>ID </th>
                <th>Frist Name </th>
                <th>Last Name </th>
                <th>Date of Enrollment </th>
                <th>Active</th>
            </tr>
        </table>
        </div>
    </div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        Manager.GetAllStudents();
    })

    var Manager = {
        GetAllStudents: function () {
            var obj = "";
            var serviceUrl = "https://localhost:5001/api/student";
            window.Manager.GetAPI(serviceUrl, onSuccess, onFailed);
            function onSuccess(jsonData) {
                obj = jsonData;
                $.each(jsonData, function (i, item) {
                    var rows = "<tr>" +
                        "<td id ='Id'>" + item.StudentId + "</td>" +
                        "<td id='First Name'>" + item.FirstName + "</td>" +
                        "<td id='Last Name'>" + item.LastName + "</td>" +
                        "<td id='Date of Enrollment'>" + item.DateOfEnrollment + "</td>" +
                        "<td id='Active'>" + item.Active + "</td>" +
                        "</tr>";
                    $('#Table').append(rows)
                });
            }
            function onFailed(error) {
                window.alert(error.statusText);
            }
            return obj;
        },

        GetAPI: function (serviceUrl, successCallback, errorCallback) {
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: serviceUrl,
                dataType: "json",
                success: successCallback,
                error: errorCallback
            });
        },
    }
</script>
```

Startup:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpsPolicy;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace WebApp
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }
        readonly string MyAllowSpecificOrigins = "_myAllowSpecificOrigins";
        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddControllersWithViews()
    .AddNewtonsoftJson(options =>
    options.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore
);
            services.AddCors(options =>
            {
                options.AddPolicy("_myAllowSpecificOrigins",
                    builder => builder
                    .AllowAnyOrigin()
                    .AllowAnyMethod()
                    .AllowAnyHeader());
            });
            services.AddControllersWithViews();
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseCors(MyAllowSpecificOrigins);
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
                // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
                app.UseHsts();
            }
            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseStaticFiles();

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Launch Settings:

```
{
  "iisSettings": {
    "windowsAuthentication": false,
    "anonymousAuthentication": true,
    "iisExpress": {
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:3315",
      "sslPort": 44303
    }
  },
  "profiles": {
    "IIS Express": {
      "commandName": "IISExpress",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    },
    "WebApp": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "applicationUrl": "https://localhost:5001;http://localhost:5000",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Student Controller

```
    using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Data;
using WebAPI.Models;
using System.Data.SqlTypes;
namespace WebAPI.Controllers

{
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class StudentController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly IConfiguration _configuration;
        public StudentController(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            _configuration = configuration;
        }

        [HttpGet]
        public JsonResult GetAllStudents()
        {
            string query = @"
                    SELECT * FROM Students";
            DataTable table = new DataTable();
            string sqlDataSource = _configuration.GetConnectionString("SchoolAppCon");
            SqlDataReader myReader;
            using (SqlConnection myCon = new SqlConnection(sqlDataSource))
            {
                myCon.Open();
                using SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand(query, myCon);
                myReader = myCommand.ExecuteReader();
                table.Load(myReader); ;

                myReader.Close();
                myCon.Close();
            }

            return new JsonResult(table);
        }
        [HttpPost]
        public JsonResult Post(Student student)
        {
            string query = @"
                    INSERT INTO Students(FirstName,LastName,DateOfEnrollment,Active) VALUES
                    ('" + student.FirstName + @"'
                    ,'" + student.LastName + @"'
                    ,'" + student.DateOfEnrollment + @"'
                    ,'" + student.Active + "')";
            DataTable table = new DataTable();
            string sqlDataSource = _configuration.GetConnectionString("SchoolAppCon");
            SqlDataReader myReader;
            using (SqlConnection myCon = new SqlConnection(sqlDataSource))
            {
                myCon.Open();
                using (SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand(query, myCon))
                {
                    myReader = myCommand.ExecuteReader();
                    table.Load(myReader); ;

                    myReader.Close();
                    myCon.Close();
                }
            }

            return new JsonResult("Added Successfully");
        }
        [HttpPut]
        public JsonResult Put(Student student)
        {
            string query = @"
                    UPDATE Students SET
                    FirstName = '" + student.FirstName + @"',
                    LastName = '" + student.LastName + @"',
                    DateofEnrollment = '" + student.DateOfEnrollment + @"',
                    Active = '" + student.Active + @"'
                    where StudentId = " + student.StudentId + @" 
                    ";
            DataTable table = new DataTable();
            string sqlDataSource = _configuration.GetConnectionString("SchoolAppCon");
            SqlDataReader myReader;
            using (SqlConnection myCon = new SqlConnection(sqlDataSource))
            {
                myCon.Open();
                using (SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand(query, myCon))
                {
                    myReader = myCommand.ExecuteReader();
                    table.Load(myReader); ;

                    myReader.Close();
                    myCon.Close();
                }
            }

            return new JsonResult("Updated Successfully");
        }
        [HttpDelete("{id}")]
        public JsonResult Delete(int id)
        {
            string query = @"
                    DELETE FROM Students
                    WHERE StudentId = " + id + @" 
                    ";
            DataTable table = new DataTable();
            string sqlDataSource = _configuration.GetConnectionString("SchoolAppCon");
            SqlDataReader myReader;
            using (SqlConnection myCon = new SqlConnection(sqlDataSource))
            {
                myCon.Open();
                using (SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand(query, myCon))
                {
                    myReader = myCommand.ExecuteReader();
                    table.Load(myReader); ;

                    myReader.Close();
                    myCon.Close();
                }
            }

            return new JsonResult("Deleted Successfully");
        }

    }
}
```

Student Module:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace WebAPI.Models
{
    public class Student
    {
        public int StudentId { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public string DateOfEnrollment { get; set; }
        public string Active { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: `Manager.GetAllStudents;` is not calling the function. Call it by adding parentheses: `Manager.GetAllStudents();`

Comment: Does onSuccess jsonData have data?

Comment: @Crowcoder Didnt even see that, changed it and now i get a method not allowed error

Comment: I don't see that you have a GetAll route available

Comment: @Crowcoder *Facepalms* you're right...i didnt even notice the service URL differed from the route

Comment: @Crowcoder Now instead of method not allowed, its an internal server error

Comment: that issue will require more detail. Can you debug the api and catch the Exception?

Comment: Okay, about to leave to drive home, will do that as soon as im Home, thank you @Crowcoder

Comment: Figured out that issue, and now it seems that my front end is connected, but instead of showing the details in the table, all the values say, undefined...There are the correct amount of rows meaning it is reading the students json data as 2 students, but for some reason showing the data as undefined

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue! It was a really stupid one too:

```
DateofEnrollment = '" + student.DateOfEnrollment + @"',
```

This line should have been:

```
DateofEnrollment = '" + student.DateofEnrollment + @"',
```

To match the database table (SQLServer) that was initially stored by the controller.